# Providing HTTP read-only access to svn checkout on a PHP server?

Tags: php, svn, webdav

I have some Subversion repositories (originally created with `svnadmin`) on a server; there is authenticated SSH read+write access via `svn+ssh://`. For certain of those SVN repositories, I would like to allow an anonymous read-only access via `http://`. The problem is I don't have administrative properties on that server, so I cannot really mess with server setups or run `svnserve`, but I can have PHP scripts. So I was wondering if there is some solution, hopefully in PHP, that would allow me to do that (implement a "bridge" to a subversion repository, that the `svn` client could check out from)?

I'd like to compare what I want to do with `git`. If I do a `git init` in a directory, I get the subfolder `.git` which contains exactly the same contents of a bare repo. I can clone this bare repo with `git clone --bare ...` and then upload it to a server - then I can directly clone using `git clone http://...` and the location of the bare repo (<sub>except that at first, `git` will complain with `fatal: ... info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`; this means that I should [enable the default post-update hook [which] runs git update-server-info to keep the information used by dumb transports (e.g., HTTP) up-to-date.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html); or run `git update-server-info` in the bare repo, so `info/refs` is generated - only then can this bare repo on server be cloned on client via HTTP</sub>).

So, I'd consider the `svnadmin` created repo (with contents `dav  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt`) to be equivalent to the `git` bare repo (as they both contain the entire history, without the actual files), so I hoped that the svnadmin repo could be setup for read-only HTTP cloning in the same way (that is, just by copying that folder contents on the server). Unfortunately, that is not so - it seems that even with HTTP access, `svn` actually communicates with a form of WebDAV on the server ([Subversion Users: Re: dav directory does not exist](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-06/1100.shtml); [SVN RedBook: What is WebDAV?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.webdav.basic.html)). So I tried [sabre/dav](http://sabre.io/) out, but after a succesful plain setup (tested with `cadaver` DAV command line tool), I can only get `svn: OPTIONS of 'http://...': 200 OK (http://...)` if I point to a svnadmin repo directory (or to its `dav/` subdirectory).

I guess what I want is probably not possible at the time:

[Re: SVN or git via WebDav using SabreDAV - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/sabredav-discuss/XKsfD2Hsn-w#!topic/sabredav-discuss/XKsfD2Hsn-w)

> The SVN protocol requires a TON of extensions to plain webdav to work. You're basically out of luck here.

... but I wanted to confirm for sure with this question...

---

Thanks to the answer from @Evert; but unfortunately `svnsync` doesn't seem to help me here (it fails with "Repository moved permanently"); here is a set of commands that I run in `bash` on an Apache server directory, with some command responses written prefixed with `#`:

```bash
svn --version
# svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053)

cd /media/www
svnadmin create mytest.svnfs
svn co file:///media/www/mytest.svnfs mytest.svn

cd mytest.svn
echo aaa >> test.txt
svn add test.txt
svn commit -m "init commit"
echo bbb >> test.txt
svn add test.txt
svn commit -m "2nd com  mit"
wget -q --no-check-certificate http://localhost/mytest.svn -O - | head --bytes 120
# <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
# <html>
#  <head>
#   <title>Index of /mytest.svn</title>

cd ..
svnadmin create mytest.mirror
cat > mytest.mirror/hooks/pre-revprop-change <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
USER="$3"

if [ "$USER" = "syncuser" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Only the syncuser user can change revprops" >&2
exit 1
EOF
chmod +x mytest.mirror/hooks/pre-revprop-change
cat > mytest.mirror/hooks/start-commit <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh

USER="$2"

if [ "$USER" = "syncuser" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Only the syncuser user may commit new revisions" >&2
exit 1
EOF
chmod +x mytest.mirror/hooks/start-commit
ls --ignore="*.tmpl" mytest.mirror/hooks/
# pre-revprop-change  start-commit

svnsync initialize file:///media/www/mytest.mirror http://localhost/mytest.svnfs/ --sync-username syncuser --sync-password syncpass
# svnsync: Repository moved permanently to 'http://localhost/mytest.svnfs/'; please relocate

# trying the working copy (even if it shouldn't work):
svnsync initialize file:///media/www/mytest.mirror http://localhost/mytest.svn/ --sync-username syncuser --sync-password syncpass
# svnsync: Repository moved permanently to 'http://localhost/mytest.svn/'; please relocate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote that answer, and it still holds true.

In a nutshell:

1. The SVN *server* can speak webdav, Delta-V (a versioning extension for webdav)
2. The SVN client takes advantage of that server, but also *requires* svn extensions.

This was true several years ago, so the situation may have changed... but I sincerely doubt it.

However.. for what you want to do, it sounds like you just want to use `svnsync`.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync

Comment: Many thanks for confirming that, @Evert; thanks for the `svnsync` pointer as well - I tried the test which is now in the OP edit, but unfortunately it fails with "Repository moved permanently" (with the exact same URL as specified). Thanks again - cheers!